# Can I use a file to specify input files/directories on Doxygen?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

Is it possible to have a file that contains the paths to all the files/directories I want Doxygen to run on? If so, how to specify it in the config file and what should the format of the file be like?

Will Doxygen be able to run if my config file looks like this?

```
INPUT = inputs.txt
```

Where

```
#file: inputs.txt
\ 
 file1.c \
 folder\file2.cpp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you specified it it is not possible but doxygen has an include mechanism for the configuration file. From the chapter ´Configuration´:

> You can also include part of a configuration file from another
>   configuration file using a @INCLUDE tag

For further details see the mentioned chapter in the documentation.